# Unrelated rspec tests fail after adding active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I'm super confused. I think I'm encountering some kind of bug. Could use some help. I had passing specs (passed dozens of times on local and CI server), and these were **completely unrelated to serializers**. Like they _just check the status of certain controller methods. But then I literally ONLY added the active_model_serializers, a UserSerializer class, and now my specs are failing. It's saying the response from my controllers is `:unauthorized` which isn't even possible, b/c I'm calling `render status: :created`.

The entire app is OSS. This is literally all that has changed: https://github.com/codeblooded/atc-api/commit/a75978a9d9a65a5e8b592685a53045e9fe6d1d91 and it's claiming that this line https://github.com/codeblooded/atc-api/blob/master/app/controllers/colors_controller.rb#L12 is a 401. Any ideas? I'm about to remove active_model_serializers and see if my tests pass again.

See my answer below. I did remove the gem, and all the unrelated tests started passing again. So, I opened a bug with the project. I think active_model_serializers must be touching some object in some unexpected way.

Comment: Without knowing stuff like what the test actually does it's hard to help, I think.

Comment: @DaveNewton It just expects the http_status_code to be :created on a post request. https://github.com/codeblooded/atc-api/blob/weird-rspec-behavior/spec/controllers/traditions_controller_spec.rb#L23 and the code it tests: https://github.com/codeblooded/atc-api/blob/weird-rspec-behavior/app/controllers/traditions_controller.rb#L12 -- notice `:unauthorized` isn't even possible to be rendered here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm pretty sure this is one of those weird bugs. I removed `active_model_serializers` gem and deleted my `UserSerializer` class. All tests pass again. I filed an issue with the project: [active_model_serializers#2168](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/2168).